# xml file parsing in android

Tags: android, xml-parsing

How can I parse my local XML file located in the systems hard disk?

Answer (score 4):

If your file is located in the /sdcard dir, you can use

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/myfile.xml");
```

If its located in your app's data directory, you can use

```
File f1=new File(context.getFilesDir(), "myfile.xml");
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);
```

If its located inside your assets/ directory, you can use:

```
AssetManager assets = context.getAssets();
InputStream in = assets.open("myfile.xml");
```

After that you can use DOM or SAX to do your XML parsing

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(in);
```